# error 'menu' was not declarated in this scope C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int x,d,p,r,se,me;
int y,s,c,op;
void calculator1()
{
    {
        start2:;
        system("color 0A") ;
        cout << "Primul Nr. " ; cin >> x ;
        cout << "Nr Doi. ";     cin >> y ;
        start1:;
        system("color 0A");
        cout << "\n 1. Suma";
        cout << "\n 2. Diferenta";
        cout << "\n 3. Produsul";
        cout << "\n 4. Catul (Fara REST)";
        cout << "\n 5. Catul (Cu REST)";
        cout << "\n Ce operatie ? ";cin >> op ;
        s = x + y;
        d = x - y;
        p = x * y;
        c = x / y;
        r = x % y;
        if(op == 1)
        {
            cout << "\n Suma \n" << s ;
            system("pause");
            cout << "1. Inapoi la calulator" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Inapoi la meniul principal";
            cin >> me;
            if(me==1){
                goto start2;
                     }
            if(me==2){
                    system("cls");
                     }
        }
        else if(op == 2)
        {
            cout << "\n Dif. \n" << d ;
            system("pause");
            cout << "1. Inapoi la calulator" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Inapoi la meniul principal";
            cin >> me;
            if(me==1){
                goto start2;
                     }
            if(me==2){
               system("cls");
                     }
        }
        else if(op == 3)
        {
            cout << "\n Prod \n" << p ;
            system("pause");
            cout << "1. Inapoi la calulator" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Inapoi la meniul principal";
            cin >> me;
            if(me==1){
                goto start2;
                     }
            if(me==2){
               system("cls");
                     }
        }
        else if(op == 4)
        {
            cout << "\n Cat. \n" << c ;
            system("pause");
            cout << "1. Inapoi la calulator" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Inapoi la meniul principal";
            cin >> me;
            if(me==1){
                goto start2;
                     }
            if(me==2){
               system("cls");
                     }
        }
        else if(op == 5)
        {
            cout << "\n Cat. " << c << " rest " << r << "\n ";
            system("pause");
            cout << "1. Inapoi la calulator" <<endl;
            cout << "2. Inapoi la meniul principal";
            cin >> me;
            if(me==1){
                    system("cls");
                goto start2;
                     }
            if(me==2){
            system("cls");
            menu();
                     }
        }
        else
        {
        system("color cf");
        cout << "\n Alegere Gresita \n" ;
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
        goto start1;
        }
}
```

and the continiue

`}
    void menu()
        {
         system("color 0A");
         cout << "1. Calculator (Simplu)\n";
         cout << "\nAlege. ";
         cin >> se ;
         if(se==1)
        {
            system("cls");
            calculator1();
          }
        }
        int main()
        {
        menu();
      }`

The full code and the compilator error :

"error: 'menu' was not declared in this scope"

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate and as compiler GNU GCC Compiler

PLEASE HELP MY !

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting as many lines or blocks of code as you can while the error still occurs. If you delete something and no longer see the error, put that thing back and delete something else. Post the smallest program you can get to produce the error, and it will be easier to tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: The indentation from hell

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a yet another silly mistake that's not a typo, but too simple and localized to be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use function `menu` inside the body of function `calculator1`. However function `menu` is declared after the definition of function `calculator1`. So the compiler does know what means name `menu` inside the body of `calculator1`

That the error will not occur you could declare function `menu` before function `calculator1` and define it after function `calculator1`

Also it is a bad idea that the functions call themselves recursively. 
Try to write the program without the recursion and goto syayements.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, every function must be declared *before* it is used. This means that before a function which calls `menu()`, you must have a declaration for menu.
Otherwise, when the compiler gets to the code that calls `menu()`, it won't know that `menu` exists.

This code will not compile:

```
int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "This is the menu function\n";
}
```

This code will compile:

```
void menu(); /* menu declaration - this line tells the compiler that menu
              * is a void function which takes no arguments
              */
int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "This is the menu function\n";
}
```

To solve your problem, put the line `void menu();` before the start of `calculator1`.